# css center align items with float

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where a floating element is interfering with the center alignment of some items in a list.  Basically I am trying to have a set of elements that are centered horizontally, and then another element floating off to the right of them.  I can do all of that, but the floating element is goofing up the math somehow.  I have tried about a dozen different placements of the elements in the HTML to no avail.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="floaty">Some Contents!</div>
    <div class="listStuff">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.floaty {
    border:solid 1px green;
    float: right;
}
.listStuff ul {
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;

    border: solid 1px blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.listStuff li {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
display:inline-block;

    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

I am kind of new to all of this HTML/CSS business, and I am beginning to think that I am barking up the wrong tree.  Can such a thing be done?

Fiddle Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YUn39/1/

Comment: Is there any way you could provide an image to show exactly what you are wanting it to do instead? That would help illustrate.

Comment: You could always absolutely position the element to take it out of the flow. The other elements won't take it into consideration - http://jsfiddle.net/7JBKT/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I guess so, but if the layout becomes more complex (and it is in practice) I would have trouble deciding that position.

Comment: @Rachel9494: The red boxes should be centered in the blue box.

Comment: I guess then I'm not sure I understand, if they are absolutely centered wouldn't that risk cutting off the green box? Or, do you mean you want to change the green box's size responsively so that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a wrapper as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/YUn39/3/):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="listStuff">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="floaty">Some Contents!</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.floaty {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border:solid 1px green;
}
.listStuff ul {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.listStuff li {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would changing your .floaty class to have absolute position be a problem or are you trying to achieve something else?

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
.floaty {
    border:solid 1px green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YUn39/2/

Comment: yes, that seems to do it.  I guess I thought that absolute positioning meant absolute to the entire doc...

Comment: as long as the parent has position set, children with position:absolute will be positioned according to the space of the parent element.  this solution is fine as long as .floaty is a direct child of body. otherwise use a wrapper like my answer below

Comment: CSS: Where 'absolute' means 'relative', but not absolutely :)